# Different texture for multiple resolution

Tags: libgdx

How to use different texture(image) for different resolution in libGDX? Also specify how to detect it from asset folder?

I have to store different resolution images in different folder that thing you guide me and please give specific example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [AssetManager](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager) to load your resources.  When loading resources, you can use different "File Resolvers" to figure out which specific asset to load based on your environment.  For a screen resolution based decision, use a `ResolutionFileResolver`.

The [AssetManagerTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/AssetManagerTest.java) demonstrates this pretty well.

Comment: Thank you for response but how I detect different resolution asset from the folder.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but generally you generate the assets *for* the specific resolutions, and put them in the folder, so you should know what you're getting.  The idea at run-time is to have the AssetManager pick one specific image, and not to look at all the possible images and compare them yourself.  This is how most Android apps work, so this might help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html